# set the coordinates of a tkinter window

Tags: python, user-interface, graphics, graph, tkinter

How would I set up the coordinates of a tkinter window (size 500x500) so that the (0,0) point is at the bottom left, and the (500x500) is at the right top?  Google hasn't been much help.

```
def graphDisplay(distance, elevation):
    '''draws up the graph.'''

    #creates a window
    root = Tk()

    #sets the name of the window
    root.title("Graph")

    #sets the size of the window
    root.geometry("500x500")

    #sets the background of the window
    root.configure(background='green')

    #create a canvas object to draw the circle
    canvas = Canvas(root)

    #runs the program until you click x
    root.mainloop
```

Comment: don't forget to call `mainloop` at the end, with: `root.mainloop()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you can't change that, but it is pretty easy, to calculate what you are looking for.

First of all, we have to notice, that `x` coordinate is the same even if the `0,0` is at the bottom-left or at the top-left corners of the canvas — so we don't have to do anything with that.

But `y` will change and it will depend on the width of canvas. So first, we have to store the width, and use it, to get the translated `y` value.

```
width = 500
root.geometry('500x{}'.format(width))
```

Now we can calculate with this width, so let's say, you want to add a point at `20,12` and the canvas is `500,500`, then `x` won't change, and we have to translate `y`:

```
translated_y = width - 12  # which will be: 500 - 12 = 488
```